# jquery slider , passing values on change of value

Tags: jquery, slider

I have created a slider  using the code ...

```
<span class='sliderspantext'>
    <div>
        <input 
            type = 'text' 
            name = 'totaldiamondstart' 
            id = 'totaldiamondstart' 
            value = '<?php echo $tot_diamond_carat_weight_start;?>' 
            size = "10" 
            onkeypress = "keypress(event,1);" 
            onblur = 'slidertotaldiamondrenew();' 
            class = 'sildertext' 
            onfocus = 'textfocchg(1,1)'
        />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type='text' 
            name = 'totaldiamondend' 
            id='totaldiamondend' 
            value = '<?php echo $tot_diamond_carat_weight_end;?>' 
            size = "10" 
            onkeypress = "keypress(event,1);" 
            onblur = 'slidertotaldiamondrenew();' 
            class = 'sildertext' 
            onfocus = 'textfocchg(2,1)'
        />
    </div>
</span>
```

I want to send the value of the slider if the value of the boxes change...

```
$("#totaldiamondstart").live("change", function() {
    alert('hello');
    var totaldiamondstart = $("#totaldiamondstart").val();
    var totaldiamondend = $("#totaldiamondend").val();
});
```

Somehow this does not work and I get no errors in the console as well, can somebody please explain why? i am using jquery 1.7.1.

The above code works if i press the submit button, but not on not `onchange`

thanks

Comment: I am sorry but a huge mess of inline css and javascript does not make me feel like debugging this... you really shouldn't write javascript this way

Comment: @romainberger removed the css.... please not if i put a submit button it works perfectly...

Comment: where is the submit button. Please post your complete markup, and JS

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. And please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) will only fire when the input element's value changes AND when it loses focus.

If you had `.change()` on a select dropdown, it would fire as soon as a user makes a new selection.

EDIT: Also, consider the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method `.live()` has been deprecated and removed as of `jQuery 1.9`. The syntax is the same in your situation.